# looping problems in c++

Tags: visual-c++

Good efternoon ,

I'm working on a matrix of number (2D array) and I want to know how to automatically obtain the sum of the elements of each line and their average. the file construct is as follows:

```
14 25 65 41 24 85 69
14 52 87 56 42 35 47
25 64 89 21 56 7  45
15 42 8  7  65 47 7
```

I used the following prtion of code:

```
for(i=0; i<7; i++){
   for (j=0; j<4; j++){ 
    double sum(0);
    sum+=M[i][j];
    average=sum/7;}}
```

but I don't get what I asked for. Any correction, please?!

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 arrays of 7 elements.
So for each array, set `sum` to zero.  for each element in the array, add it to `sum`. then calculate the average.

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
   double sum(0);
   for (j=0; j<7; j++){ 
    sum+=M[i][j];
   }
   average=sum/7;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add them element by element, because in reality I have 100 rows and 200 columns, then you can imagine how big my code will be !
I want a loop that adds automatically all the elements of each line, and for all the lines

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in "sumOfArray()" function.  If there was, it would have to loop through each element in the array and add them up.  And unless you're working on a old 8088 processor, 100 rows with 200 elements each isn't going to take that long.